# Swift Table View Delegate Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
class ListVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var listTable: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["A", "B", "C"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.listTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.listTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Above is my Code in view controller, but I am getting error saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[R_Test.ListVC tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8f9c22e40'

Comment: Remove `;` from  `return self.items.count;` and then try.

Comment: @agent_stack It doesn't matter if you put comma also

Comment: set table delegate and dataSource 
listTable.delegate = self
listTable.dataSource = self
Also add protocols - UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource

Comment: it is many scenario's will occur

Comment: How is the datasource set of your `listTable`?

Comment: no removing ; not helping

Comment: Refer to agent_stack' s answer if you still get an error try checking the value  of self.items.count by logging it. Might be possible that its returning a nil value. Or you can try hard coding the expression to check out.

Comment: What version of swift are you using?

Comment: listTable.delegate = self
listTable.dataSource = self

Maybe delegate missing. set above method in viewDidLoad

Comment: Swift 3.0.. Thanku all for your answers and suggestions.

Comment: The code you posted is not Swift 3. You have all the wrong signatures for the table view methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `class ListVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.listTable.dataSource = self
    self.listTable.delegate = self
    self.listTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class ListVC: UIViewController
```

to

```
class ListVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

and in `VDL`

```
listTable.delegate = self
listTable.dataSource = self
```

Comment: It is saying use of undeclared type UITableViewDatasource

Comment: @Ren `UITableViewDatasource ` to `UITableViewDataSource ` I mean capital `S`.

Answer (score -1):

You can change `class ListVC: UIViewController` to `class ListVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource`, and then add the following code in your `didLoad()` method:

```
self.listTable.dataSource = self
self.listTable.delegate = self
```